# bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;;'

Tags: git, git-bash

I have a github project, where inside my directory there is a file called "app;;settings.dat".

When I want to add this file to commit,  I write the following command:

```
git add app;;settings.dat
```

but it gives me the following error:

> bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;;'

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`;` is a special character in Bash (it's used to separate commands on a single line).  Try this:

```
git add "app;;settings.dat"
```

(And more generally, try to avoid using `;` in filenames!)

Comment: fatal: pathspec 'app;;setings.dat' did not match any files

Comment: @cssGEEK: Works on my machine.  The error implies that your file isn't really called that - can you add the output of `ls` to your question?

Comment: I have bash on windows and when I run the your command it gives me the above error

Comment: @cssGEEK: Oh if you're using Windows, I have no idea :(

Comment: @cssGEEK: Other than to avoid the problem entirely by not using awkward characters in filenames (it's going to make your life difficult in so many ways, even if you solve this particular instance).

Comment: This file name was a result of a wrong java code I wrote .lol :p

Answer (score 1):

`;` is special character bash. You have to escape it.

Try

`git add app\;\;settings.dat`

Comment: fatal: pathspec 'app;;settings.dat' did not match any files

Comment: Are you sure the file is present by name app;;settings.dat